# Google Rich Snippets wont show - Microformat hreview-aggregate

Tags: code-snippets

Hye there,

Can anyone tell why my Google Rich Snippets wont show?
I've already read the help page of google (also this website for solutions) and cound't find anything wrong with my snippets.

Reasons why it shoud show:

- It is on the web for weeks now.
- it passes Google validator (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vapeware.nl%2FWebwinkel%2FActies%2FSigelei-ZMax-V5-Kit%2F)
- The html is clean (xhtml strict without errors)
- The html is not hidden for visitors

Possible reason why it shoudn't show:

- The html doctype needs to be html5 (I can't beleave that?)

Here is the snippet part:

```
<p>
<span class="hreview-aggregate">
After <span class="votes">5</span> vote(s) the article <span class="item">"<span class="fn">Sigelei-20W</span>"</span> was rated (<span class="rating">within a scale from 1 to <span class="best">5</span>) with <span class="average">4.8</span> stars.</span>
</span>
</p>
```

The full html can be found here:
http://www.vapeware.eu/Webshop/E-cigarettes/Sigelei/Sigelei-20W/

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally I found out the possible reason myself.
Now one month later (for some total other reason :)) I've converted my website form xhtml strict to html5.
Now the snippets are appearing in the search results.

I hope it helps someone else.